# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () SpringBoot

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to call external javaScript function in my HTML. When I open the local HTML file URL in Intellij Idea, the HTML will appear as expected. However, when I try to run the web application, the javaScript function will not appear. When I press F12 on the webpage, it mentions:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () for the script.js.

I tried to use the absolute path for my javaScript file but the same problem persists. May I know how do I fix this? Below are my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>New Employee Form</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
       form {
         text-align: center;
         padding: 40px 0;
         background: #EBF0F5;
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.5/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.5/additional-methods.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">New Employee Form</h1>
    <hr>
    <h2 style="text-align:center;">Save Employee</h2>

    <div id="ERRORS"> </div>
    <form  id="form" action="#" th:action="@{/saveEmployee}" th:object="${employee}"
          method="POST">
        <span class="error_form" id="fname_error_message"></span>
        <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"
               placeholder="Employee First Name" class="form-control mx-auto col-8 mb-3"  >

        <span class="error_form" id="lname_error_message"></span>
        <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" th:field="*{lastName}"
               placeholder="Employee Last Name" class="form-control mx-auto col-8 mb-3" >

        <span class="error_form" id="email_error_message"></span>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" th:field="*{email}"
               placeholder="Employee Email" class="form-control mx-auto col-8 mb-3" >

      <br>

        <button type="submit " class="btn btn-info col-2"> Save Employee</button>

    </form>

    <a th:href = "@{/employeeList}" class="btn btn-info col-2 "> View Employee</a>
    <hr>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is where I save my HTML and javascript file.
[image: resources]

Comment: What exactly fails to load? Your own script.js?

Comment: Hi, yes, my own script failed to load (script.js)

Comment: Open your HTML file from a browser, are the `th` attributes still present?

Comment: Hi, everything is still present when I open the HTML file from browser

Answer (score 0):

you could try to move the `script.js` file into the directory of the project to fix the issue or you could try just copying `javascript` code straight into `HTML` in the `<script></script>` tag.

Comment: Hi, initially I was including the script.js file inside HTML file and it works. However, I would like to try to separate javaScript file from HTML file since the javaScript file is lengthy and it is exposed to the client side. My script.js is also saved in the directory of the project

Comment: I see, could you provide the project's hierarchy, because the code says it couldn't find it, maybe the issue lies there

Comment: Hi, I just added the image, please have a look

Comment: thanks! have you tried putting the script.js file into the STATIC folder? the name seems to suggest it may be used to store static files for html to access, these kinds of folders are either named STATIC or PUBLIC

Comment: I did try to put the file into the STATIC folder, same error

Comment: it seems like there's a template folder, could you create a template for a head tag or for a script tag, put your code there and link it to the index.html? (like a headTag.html with links and whatnot or a scriptJS.html with the script tag and code)